# how can I change my google developer account email which shown in play.google?

Tags: android, google-play

how can I change my google developer account email which shown in play.google ?

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set different email for each app you publish, from the app listing page in the developer console.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Click on the app name, scroll to bottom, change *Email* option

Comment: I try it now and give feed back to you